# How does location matter while creating a Global HTTPS Google Cloud Load Balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I am creating a global HTTPS Load Balancer in Google Cloud and wondering how does location affect a global load balancer.

I am unable to find much detail about it on internet.

There are price differences based on location:
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#lb

but no idea how it affects routing of https requests:
https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-cloudblog-publish/images/global_lb.max-1800x1800.png

For example: if my website receives most of its traffic from USA, India and Europe then what would be the best location I should choose while setting up global HTTPS Load Balancer and what difference it will make?

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference is that the global load balancing is for Layer-7 (high-level application layer) traffic while regional load balance is for Layer-4 (transport layer) traffic and uses [Maglev](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/google-cloud-networking-in-depth-cloud-load-balancing-deconstructed) for traffic routing.

Let's say you want to do your own SSL terminations and operate your own Layer-7 reverse proxies, I believe regional is the correct option.  For the vast majority of users I would wager that global is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation [Cloud Load Balancing overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview) section [Global versus regional load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#global_versus_regional_load_balancing):

> Use **global load balancing** when your backends are distributed
> across multiple regions, your users need access to the same
> applications and content, and you want to provide access by using a
> single anycast IP address. Global load balancing can also provide IPv6
> termination.
>
> Use **regional load balancing** when your backends are in one region,
> and you only require IPv4 termination.

and at section [External HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#external-https-load-balancing):

> [HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) is implemented on GFEs. GFEs are
> [distributed globally](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/locations) and operate together using Google's global
> network and control plane. In Premium Tier, GFEs offer [cross-regional
> load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#cross-region_load_balancing), directing traffic to the closest healthy backend that
> has capacity and terminating HTTP(S) traffic as close as possible to
> your users.

more information about Network Service Tiers you can find in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/overview#configuring_standard_tier_for_https_lb_and_tcpssl_proxy).

To find more details have a look at the documentation [External HTTP(S) Load Balancing overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https):

> HTTP(S) Load Balancing is a global service when the Premium [Network
> Service Tier](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/overview) is used.

and

> 1. When a user request comes in, the load balancing service determines the approximate origin of the request from the source IP address.
> 2. The load balancing service knows the locations of the instances owned by the backend service, their overall capacity, and their
>    overall current usage.
> 3. If the closest instances to the user have available capacity, the request is forwarded to that closest set of instances.
> 4. Incoming requests to the given region are distributed evenly across all available backend services and instances in that region. However,
>    at very small loads, the distribution may appear to be uneven.
> 5. If there are no healthy instances with available capacity in a given region, the load balancer instead sends the request to the next
>    closest region with available capacity.

also

> HTTP(S) Load Balancing is a regional service when the Standard Network
> Service Tier is used. Its backend instance groups or NEGs must all be
> located in the region used by the load balancer's external IP address
> and forwarding rule.

Meanwhile, [Maglev](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#external-tcp-udp-network-load-balancing) is a distributed system for [Network Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network).